# Twitter Bootstrap Menu stopped working after installing Joomla module

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope someone can help me because I am out of ideas.

Here is a site, in which I am trying to use Twitter bootstrap. 
It worked perfectly. No problems what so ever. Then suddenly, the dropdown menu stopped working, after I installed some Joomla modules... I tried to repair it, but instead chose to built the website from scratch again.

And again the bootstrap menu worked perfectly, just until I installed some Joomla modules again, and since then it just does not work anymore. Now I deinstalled every single module with the hope, to find why it isn't working anymore... but I just don't know.

Here is the site:
***http://bootstrap.horyzon.de***

I tried to make a fiddle, but it won't work properly, because it doesn't get responsive:

http://jsfiddle.net/ff9EW/

```
I hope someone can give me a solution to this.
```

Comment: "...some Joomla modules"?

Comment: Yes... for example "Yootheme - Widgetkit", "Easyblog", "Ajax Improved Login and Register"... I don't know which of them handled the brake, but I deinstalled every one of them and the menu still does not work...

Comment: What version of Joomla? If it's a new site, consider going to 3.1.x. You may be seeing a conflict with mootools. I see this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return h} has no method 'trim'

Comment: It is a fresh new installation of Joomla 3.1.1 Stable. Do you suggest, that I somehow disable the mootools? I used the firefox and the chrome console, but didn't get any response at all... What do you suggest exactly, because I did not understand?

Comment: BTW: I have to go right now... can be for answers back in some hours again.

Comment: I was under the mistaken impression that mootools was not part of Joomla 3 core. I see that I'm wrong about that. Until you discover which module caused the breakage, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be always a conflict between the MooTools Javascript and the jQuery that I inserted manually.

There is no way to make it disappear accept if you are using this plugin:

[Mootools jQuery Disabler](http://digitaldisseny.com/en/joomla-extensions/disable-mootools-joomla-per-itemid-solve-jquery-conflicts)

Now it works perfectly.